# Why some of my pages on ReadTheDocs are not shown?

Tags: python, documentation, read-the-docs

On [DiddiLeija/text_formatter](http://github.com/DiddiLeija/text_formatter), I am building documentation with ReadTheDocs. At this moment, I have this file tree on a `docs` folder on the repo:

```
docs/
|- modules/
   |- index.rst
   |- module_justify.rst
   |- module_check.rst
|- conf.py
|- index.rst
|- requirements.txt
```

But when I open my ReadTheDocs site (http://text-formatter.readthedocs.io), I can only see the content from `docs/index.rst`. Can somebody check my problem, and tell me what am I doing wrong here?

(The original GitHub issue is [here](https://github.com/DiddiLeija/text_formatter/issues/29)).

Comment: I've been thinking to ask on the GitHub ReadTheDocs repository, but I consider this is my mistake, not a ReadTheDocs bug.

Comment: Use the index.rst file to link them all: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553750/how-can-i-link-reference-another-rest-file-in-the-documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer at article ["How can I link/reference another reST file in the documentation?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413256/16246013), it was really useful for me. Thanks [Dioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12927874/dioni) for pointing me there!